# SMARTS: distinguish between alcohol and carboxylic acid

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

I'm new to SMARTS and have to identify substructures with the Python package `rdkit`, so far so good. Let's say I have a SMILES with an carboxylic acid and a alcohol such as

```
OC(C1=CC(CO)=CC=C1)=O
```

and I want to get only the alcohol, then I would try something like this:

```python
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("OC(C1=CC(CO)=CC=C1)=O") 
    toSearch = Chem.MolFromSmarts("[#6][OX2H]")
    bool = mol.HasSubstructMatch(toSearch)
    subStruct = mol.GetSubstructMatches(toSearch)
    print(bool)
    print(subStruct)
```

which would return:
[image]

```
True
((1, 0), (5, 6))
```

However, the substructure search also identifies the OH of the acid which I don't want. How can I exclude that? My idea was to use some kind of recursive smarts for the alcohol to exclude all those "alcohols" where the carbon is bonded to another oxygen like "=O".

Comment: Hello! You may also be interested in the [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) 'sister site'. (though please don't post questions twice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest change to make for your SMARTS pattern would be specifying the total degree of the attached carbon is 4 with `"[#6X4][OX2H]"`. This is enough to discriminate against the carboxylic acid.

You could use the alcohol SMARTS from [here](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/blob/master/data/SMARTS_InteLigand.txt#L70), which has the comment

> nonspecific definition, no acetals, aminals, and the like

The SMARTS pattern is `"[OX2H][CX4;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])]"`, which stipulates that the carbon attached to the oxygen not also be connected to O, S, N, or P.

I made a little [interactive widget](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/37fe8f9e-7c80-447c-a589-92e94d9197c4) that takes a molecule name or SMILES in the first field and a SMARTS pattern in the second.

Comment: Awesome!!!! 
Thanks for the answer and the two great links! I have one more question. This smart doesn't hit if the alcohol is on an aromatic carbon. In this Case this smarts  "[OX2H][CX4,c;!$(C([OX2H])[O,S,#7,#15])]" should work, shouldn't it? thx!

Comment: @dideldideldum - that does seem to work:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIfOp.png

Comment: The [smarts.plus](https://smarts.plus) website is also useful for visualizing / debugging SMARTS patterns.